# The argument type 'BuildContext' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'OverlayState'. top_snackbar_flutter: ^3.0.0

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-snackbar, snackbar

```
showTopSnackBar(
    context,
    CustomSnackBar.success(
      message:
          "Good job, your release is successful. Have a nice day",
    ),
);
```

***top_snackbar_flutter: ^3.0.0***

Answer (score 0):

There is the simple solution you should apply;

```
OverlayState? state = Overlay.of(context);
    showTopSnackBar(
    state,
    CustomSnackBar.success(
      message:
          "Good job, your release is successful. Have a nice day",
    ),
);
```